# Need two different version JARs in one Java app

Tags: java, maven, jar, classloader

I have a Java application that includes two third party JARs (Amazon Kinesis and MaxMind GeoIP2), each using a different version of Jackson.  Neither version of Jackson works with both of the third party JARs.

Furthermore, I am running Apache's maven JAR pluging - which creates an uber JAR containing all dependent classes.

Given that I can't change the third party JARs, I don't know how I'm going to be able to accomplish having each third party JAR call the appropriate version JARs of Jackson.

Any ideas?

Kinesis is expecting: 
`com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat` » `jackson-dataformat-cbor:2.6.6`
`com.fasterxml.jackson.core` » `jackson-databind:2.6.6`

And GeoIP2 is expecting:
`com.fasterxml.jackson.core` » `jackson-databind:2.8.8.1`

Comment: Can you please share the co-ordinates for `Amazon Kinesis` and `MaxMind GeoIP2`?

Comment: If "co-ordinates" refers to JAR versions, please see the updated original post.  If not, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for maven GAV co-ordinates of `Amazon Kinesis` and `MaxMind GeoIP2`.

Comment: Load Kinesis and its dependencies into one classloader, and GeoIP2 into another. From your code where you need to call them, do not make explicit calls, instead get instances out of the corresponding classloader, and use reflection to operate on them. Truth be told, you'd probably be better off downgrading one of them so that they can use the same Jackson version...

Comment: What happens if only jackson-databind 2.8.8.1 is in your classpath at runtime?

Comment: Amazon Kinesis blows up.

Comment: After reviewing the various possibilities, I opted to downgrade my GeoIP2 JAR to a version using the same Jackson JAR as AWS Kinesis needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use Maven shade plugin

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html

to relocate classes.

Comment: Given that both third party JARs are looking for a specific classpath would this solution work?